# How to get values inside object got through Json

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, .net, json

I am using .NET MVC4

I have used javascript function as below:

```
function ShowDomainComponentDetail(compCode) {
        alert(compCode);
        $.ajax({
            url: "/PP/getDomainComponentDetailWithDomain",
            data: {
                'ComponentCode': compCode
            },
            dataType: "json",
            type: 'POST',
            cache: false,
            success: function (_responseData) {
                $('#divShowDomainCompDetail').show();
                alert(_responseData.Data)

            },
            error: function () {
                //
            }
        });
    }
```

Upon success I am getting list in .net as:

```
IdObservation=1, ObservationName="Started" , ObsType="Announced";
IdObservation=2, ObservationName="Not Started" , ObsType="Un Announced";
IdObservation=3, ObservationName="Declared" , ObsType="Announced";
```

My problem is i am not abl;e to access this list inside Ajax sucess block.

How can i access this list as:

```
alert(_responseData.IdObservation);
alert(_responseData.ObservationName);
```

(Further i am going to assign this to labels).

Please help me.

**EDIT 1 :**

My Serverside Function returning list:

```
public JsonResult getDomainComponentDetailWithDomain(string ComponentCode)
        {
            try
            {
                List<TEAMS_PP.Entity.correlations> compDetail_list = new correlation().getDomainComponentDetailswithDomain(ComponentCode);
                return Json(compDetail_list);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                List<TEAMS_PP.Entity.correlations> BlankList = new List<TEAMS_PP.Entity.correlations>();
                return Json(BlankList);
            }
        }
```

Comment: How are you returning the list from the server?

Comment: @James plz look at EDIT1

Comment: Cool was just making sure you were sending it back correctly, your result is simple an array of objects (you can see that if you use the debugger). See @Bhushan's answer below.

Comment: @James Yes that answer worked!!! Thanks for sharing time with my question :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use index with data object like below:

```
alert(_responseData[0].IdObservation);
```

loop through object and get values for each object.

Comment: tumacha swagat aahe :)

Answer (score 1):

you can use the $each to iterate it

```
$.each(_responseData, function (key, value) {
                        var arr = value.IdObservation;
                    });
```